# Angular-cli SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Tags: json, angular, angular-cli

I just pulled the new version of my project with git and angular-cli stopped working. When I start it, I get the following error:

```
Parsing .angular-cli.json failed. Please make sure your .angular-cli.json is valid JSON. Error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1044
InvalidConfigError: Parsing .angular-cli.json failed. Please make sure your .angular-cli.json is valid JSON. Error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1044
```

My angular-cli.json file is the following:

```
{
    "project": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
        "name": "quest"
    },
    "apps": [
        {
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist",
            "assets": [
                "assets"
            ],
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "mobile": false,
            "styles": [
                "styles.less",
                "../node_modules/angular2-toaster/toaster.css",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap-slider/dist/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.css",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
                "../node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/app.js",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap-slider/dist/bootstrap-slider.js",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
            ],
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        }
    ],
    "addons": [],
    "packages": [],
    "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
            "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "test": {
        "karma": {
            "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "css",
        "prefixInterfaces": false,
        "inline": {
            "style": false,
            "template": false
        },
        "spec": {
            "class": false,
            "component": true,
            "directive": true,
            "module": false,
            "pipe": true,
            "service": true
        }
    }
}
```

I tried updating `angular-cli`, I tried deleting `node_modules` et running `npm install`. I have node version 6.9.5. I tried parsing the `angular-cli.json` with some JSON validation tools.

Any other idea?

Comment: Rename config file from `angular-cli.json` to `.angular-cli.json` Notice **point**

Comment: Fixed it, the wrong version of the project was opened in my IDE. Sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: Please , put the  a like this `"project": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
        "name": "quest",
    },`